# Turning off the options() debugging mode in R

Tags: r

In R I can activate debugging mode through `options(error=recover)`. **How can I turn it off?** I tried `options()` and `options(NULL)` and `options(default=NULL)` but none of them seem to turn of the functionality activated by `options(error=recover)`.

Comment: To see all currently defined options, try one or all of `names(options())`, `names(.Options)` or `?options`. The `options` function gives you access to the `.Options` list. If there is no value, then you get `NULL` when you try to access a named value.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try this :

```
options(error=NULL)
```

To show that it works:

```
options(error=recover)
rnorm("k")
# Error in rnorm("k") : invalid arguments
# In addition: Warning message:
# In rnorm("k") : NAs introduced by coercion
# 
# Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   
# 
# 1: rnorm("k")
# 
Selection: 0

options(error=NULL)
rnorm("k")
# Error in rnorm("k") : invalid arguments
# In addition: Warning message:
# In rnorm("k") : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: By default,  `getOption(x = "error")` gives a non-null function. Perhaps that should be set to go back to default behavior. Do we lose something by setting `options(error=NULL)`?